# Tuple evaluation

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function of the following type:

```
match :: [(String,a)] -> Maybe (String, a, a)
```

I want the function to traverse the list of tuples, and determine if there are any tuples in which the first element (a string) is the same. If so, I want to return a tuple containing that string, as well as the second element in each of those matching tuples. If there are no matching tuples, return "Nothing". If there is more than one matching, return the first one it finds.

For example:

```
match [("x", 3), ("y", 4), ("z", "5"), ("x", 6)] = ("x", 3, 6)
match [("x", 3), ("y", 4), ("z", "5")] = Nothing
```

I'm thinking:

```
match (x:xs) = if (fst x) = (fst xs) return (fst x, snd x, snd xs)
--if no matches, return Nothing
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I assume the ("z","5") was a misprint, because none of the other numbers have quotes.

Answer (score 2):

What if there are three or four tuples with "x"? You can't have variable-length tuples. Maybe you want to return a list:

```
match :: [(String, a)] -> Maybe (String, [a])
```

What if there are several tuples that match? Do you want them all, or just the first? If you want them all then you should return a list of matches.

```
match :: [(String, a)] -> [(String, [a])]
```

If you think of it like this, then you can see that grouping all the "x" pairs together, and "y" pairs, and so on, would be a good start. You can do this by using

```
sortBy (comparing fst) xs
```

`comparing` takes a function and two values, applies the function to each, and compares the results. `sortBy` uses its first argument as a comparison function, so `sortBy (comparing fst)` sorts your list into order by the first element in each tuple.

Then you can use `groupBy` to collect the elements together.

Edit:

`groupBy` has the type

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

So you need to write a function `equalFirst` to give it as a parameter. So then

```
groupBy equalFirst $ sortBy (comparing fst) xs
```

will give you

```
[[("x", 3), ("x", 6)], [("y", 4)], [("z", 5)]]
```

Which is a list of lists. Each sub-list contains tuples with the same letter.

Now you can write a function which takes one of these sublists and converts it into the result you want. Then apply it to the list of lists using `map`.

Comment: For this function let's assume that there is only one matching tuple, and only two of the tuples have "x"

Comment: @Sarah.S: Then use pattern matching to convert from the list of results to the three-element tuple you want.